# Get most frequent value(s) from a list of lists

Tags: r, list

I am trying to convert an LDA prediction result, which is a `list` object containing hundred of `list` (of topics (in `numeric`) assigned to each token in a document), such as the following example

```
assignments <- list(
  as.integer(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3)),
  as.integer(c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3)),
  as.integer(c(1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2))
)
```

where each list of the `list` object has different length corresponding to the length of each tokenized document.

What I want to do are to 1) get the most frequent topic (1, 2, 3) out of each list, and 2) convert them into `tbl` or `data.frame` format like this

```
document  topic   freq
   1        1       6
   2        2       5
   3        3       6
```

such that I can use `inner_join()` to merge this "consensus" prediction with the topic assignment results generated by `tm` or `topicmodels` applications and compare their precision, etc. Since the `assignments` is in `list` format, I cannot apply `top_n()` function to get the most frequent topic for each list. I tried sing `lapply(unlist(assignments), count)`, but it didn't give me what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate over the list with `sapply`, get frequency with `table` and extract first value from sorted result:

```
result <- sapply(assignments, function(x) sort(table(x), decreasing = TRUE)[1])
data.frame(document = seq_along(assignments),
           topic = as.integer(names(result)),
           freq = result)
```

> ```
>   document topic freq
> 1        1     1    6
> 2        2     2    5
> 3        3     3    6
> ```

Comment: Thanks, your suggested answer is much easier to implement. I will also experiment with @akrun's answer.

Answer (score 1):

We can loop through the `list`, get the frequency of elements with `tabulate`, find the index of maximum elements, extract those along with the frequency as a `data.frame` and `rbind` the `list` elements

```
do.call(rbind,  lapply(seq_along(assignments), function(i) {
        x <- assignments[[i]]
        ux <- unique(x)
        i1 <- tabulate(match(x, ux))
    data.frame(document = i, topic = ux[which.max(i1)], freq = max(i1))})
 )
#    document topic freq
#1        1     1    6
#2        2     2    5
#3        3     3    6
```

---

Or another option is to convert it to a two column dataset and then do group by to find the index of max values

```
library(data.table)
setDT(stack(setNames(assignments, seq_along(assignments))))[,
  .(freq = .N), .(document = ind, topic = values)][, .SD[freq == max(freq)], document]
#    document topic freq
#1:        1     1    6
#2:        2     2    5
#3:        3     3    6
```

---

Or we can use `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
map(assignments, as_tibble) %>% 
    bind_rows(.id = 'document') %>% 
    count(document, value) %>% 
    group_by(document) %>%
    filter(n == max(n)) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    rename_at(2:3, ~c('topic', 'freq'))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  document topic  freq
#  <chr>    <int> <int>
#1 1            1     6
#2 2            2     5
#3 3            3     6
```

Answer (score 1):

using `purrr::imap_dfr` :

```
library(tidyverse)
imap_dfr(assignments,~ tibble(
  document = .y,
  Topic = names(which.max(table(.x))),
  freq  = max(tabulate(.x))))

# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#   document Topic  freq
#      <int> <chr> <int>
# 1        1     1     6
# 2        2     2     5
# 3        3     3     6
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.

Comment: it's less efficient that other propositions as I'm summarizing twice, but more readable.